# Prolog Querying: Unifying a variable in a nested compund Term

Tags: prolog

I have a set of Prolog facts which I am attempting to query, but I am having trouble figuring out how to unify variables that are more deeply nested. An example of a fact in the database is as follows:

```
character(super,mario, type(human)).
character(donkey,kong, type(ape)).

videogame(year(1991), console(nintendo), title([super,mario,bros]), characters([character(super,mario), character(princess,peach)])).
videogame(year(1999), console(nintendo), title([super,smash,bros]), characters([character(super,mario), character(donkey,kong)])).
```

So for example, I want to query which characters appear in more than 1 video game. So I know that I want to create two instances of videogame and ensure that the same character appears (by name) in both games, and that those games are not the same game (by title).

Thus I would do something like:

```
?- videogame(_, _, title(Title1), characters(?????)), videogame(_, _, title(Title2), characters(?????)), not(Title1 == Title2).
```

However, my issue has been finding a way to create variables within the characters portion such that the "first" and "last" name of the characters unifies with a character that appears in more than one videogame.

I have tried things along the lines of the following (to fill in the question marks above in the full query) to try and unify the first and last name of the character, but they produce the error:

```
characters(character[First,Last])
characters([First, Last])


 ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
```

I have also tried the following, which just returns `false.`

```
?- videogame(_, _, title(Title1), _), videogame(_, _, title(Title2), _), member(actor(First,Last,_), cast), not(Title1 == Title2).
```

I would appreciate some help so that I can gain a better understanding of how query in Prolog even in the presence of more nested terms.

Comment: This is a list  not a title `title([super,mario,bros])`

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I am aware it is in list structure, although I have the titles put into this structure in the database. I am more concerned with the querying of these lists, in particular the characters list because it is the most nested.

Comment: is `super,mario` one character or two?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim Sorry for the confusion of that portion, I have it acting in a first name, last name fashion where super = first name and mario = last name, but it is one character. So I want the first and last name to unify for the character to be considered in more than 1 video game.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim so from the facts in the database sample provided, super mario should be the character returned that is a character in multiple video games, while princess peach and donkey kong are characters that do not appear in multiple video games.

Comment: Every clause has to end with at `.`. That's the reason for the errors.

Comment: @false, every clause I have does end with a `.`. This is not the issue I am having. The statements above `characters(character[First,Last])` and `characters([First, Last])` fill in the question marks as I indicated meaning that a `.` is not meant to end the clause as it continues.

Comment: Well there is another error: `character[` that should read `character([ ...`

Comment: @false Fair enough although it still doesn't work either way.

Comment: Please read [this](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with [intersection](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=intersection/3)/3 from library(lists) I would write

```
?- videogame(_,_,title(Title1),characters(Cs1)), videogame(_,_,title(Title2),characters(Cs2)), Title1 @< Title2, intersection(Cs1,Cs2,Common).
```